# Best method for running a "common" REST call before any other REST call

Tags: android, rest, jersey, retrofit, jwt

I have a REST API secured with JWT. The client is an Android app and a web app. Android app gets a new token when a user login, after that it works with that token. However the token will expire in 60 minutes, so I have to refresh it. I know there are 3 approaches for this.

- issue a fresh token in every request
- issue a fresh token when the current one is close to expire. e.g. 10
  min
- let client app request a new token when it needs it using a "refresh
  service" of your api.

Please consider the following...

- I am not happy about the first suggestion above
- I did try the third suggestion. However in my android app I got like 60 REST calls. Then what I should be doing is with every REST call (ex: `getUsers()`), I first have to check whether the token is about to expire and if yes, get a new token from REST API (That means I have to run another REST call to the `refresh()` method in API). After this check and getting the new token I can execute the `getUsers()` method. The problem here is that every REST call should run inside the `onResponse()` method of my `refresh()` method (I am using Retrofit) and that is simply not possible as I have to then duplicate the same method for 60 times with 60 names. I am sure the same issue will arise with the web app as well.

Due to the above reasons I am considering the 2nd suggestions in my first list, renewing the token at the server it self. If the token is "valid" and if it is "about to expire" I will refresh it from server and will send to app as a header.

I need to know whether that method is an industry practicing method and whather it is the best choice. If not, how I can proceed with the 3rd suggestion in my first list.

Answer (score 0):

*I have recently implemented the similar setup with JWT in one of my Android apps. I don't know if my suggestion will help you, but it might give you an insight on how others are doing it.*

**Option 1:** This is very much redundant, and it violates the sole purpose of using JWT in the first place. If I get a new JWT on every request, I can use that for further requests, thus practically have a token with no expiration.

**Option 2:** This requires server side extra operation, plus this is not feasible. How do you plan to detect which tokens are already distributed and "about to expire" so that you can renew them? Tons of users will have tons of tokens and if you plan to save JWT in database, then it would get too messy.

**Option 3:** This method is too redudndant and requires client side operation on checking whether token is about to expire and calling refresh service based on that. I always prefer lesser operation to do more work.

---

**What I did, is that,** I used two tokens for the system. One as a **Refresh Token** *(token used to request JWT refresh)* and one as **JWT** *(for every request validation)*.

With successful login, received a refresh token and saved it locally in app *(SharedPref)*. This token is also preserved in database too. Next, requested and validated JWT with that with that refresh token. From now onwards, every request contains this JWT in header. I also request new JWT everytime when my app is opened, i.e, in my Splash page.

Now, if any request contains expired JWT, simply return a common response like *"Session expired"* with a fixed status code. If any HTTP request has this specific status code in its response, I requested another API call with the refresh token to get fresh JWT for future requests.

As I needed to add this check (whether contains *"Session Expired"*) in every HTTP response, I wrote a common function and passed the HTTP responses via that method, so that, I do not need to rewrite or copy-paste every bit of it.

This requires very less code and minimal operation on both server and app end. My system has a JWT expiration time of 20 minutes and I haven't faced any problem till now. Worst what happens is, in a single request, user receives token expired, gets token, and recalls that function. This results in a slightly delayed operation for users that is already in my app continuously for more than 20 minutes. If any user is in my app for that long, it's a good problem to have, right? :)

It's not clear whether the users have to log-in in your app every time or session is held so that logged-in users can directly enter the app. If session is hold, just keep the refreshToken in app locally *(SharedPref)* and use that to get JWT every time the app is opened. If any user is misusing your API (scraping or for any other purpose), simply move that specific refresh token to a black-list so that this user doesn't get new JWT.

Please let me know if anything's not clear. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. `This requires server side extra operation, plus this is not feasible. How do you plan to detect which tokens are already distributed and "about to expire" so that you can renew them? Tons of users will have tons of tokens and if you plan to save JWT in database, then it would get too messy.` - I can't agree. JWT has the expiration claim, and it require no database. If a token is valid then it is already distributed, if it has username claim then we know to whom it went, if it has expiration date then we know when will expire.

Comment: `As I needed to add this check (whether contains "Session Expired") in every HTTP response, I wrote a common function and passed the HTTP responses via that method, so that, I do not need to rewrite or copy-paste every bit of it.` - So, you need to write the other method inside of the mentioned method's `onResponse` right? Otherwise if both ran at once it would be an issue; how did you do this ?

Comment: Okay, I didn't understand the approach you said here then, but I get it now. This seems like a variant of my suggestion, moving the operation from client end to distributing between server end and client end. This solution results in a single API call, so might be a bit faster than mine. 

But I didn't get one problem though, what if the user logs in, get a JWT, moves the app to backstack and reopens the app from backstack after 60 minutes or more? How is this case handled? I have frequently faced this case, as most users don't close the app, just opens another app on top of it.